# Зачем нужно обособление фразы «в переводе»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Наткнулся на вот такое предложение: «Недавно Совнарком утвердил порядок присуждения квалификации, или, в переводе на простой язык, присуждение звания» (И. Ходоровский. На фронте просвещения (1923-1925)

Разве здесь недостаточно запятой перед союзом «или»? Как, например, расставить запятые в следующих примерах:

1. Home, или в переводе с английского «дом».
2. Здесь было написано «Ursus ' Den», или в переводе с латыни «Берлога медведя».

Comment: Оно так произносится, обособленно.

Comment: Слово "присуждение" повторяется в разных падежах, и получается, что "Совнарком утвердил порядок, или присуждение". Думаю, в переводе на простой язык нуждалась "квалификация" и повтор не нужен: "...утвердил порядок присуждения квалификации, или звания".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1. Или в качестве перевода на простой язык "присуждение звания"
2. Или как перевод на простой язык "присуждение звания"
3. Или переводя на простой язык "присуждение звания"
```

Здесь у нас во всех трех предложениях оборот с непервообразным предлогом.
Такие обороты любят обособлять, хотя в школе есть правило - не ставить запятую перед **как** в значении **в качестве**.

Comment: В примере 3 без запятых: *Или переводя на простой язык [фразу] "присуждение звания".*

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, что именно здесь является непервообразным предлогом?

Comment: Ну очевидно, что "переводя на" потеряло связь с субъектом и действием. Следовательно его надо считать либо предлогом, либо вводным. По аналогии со всякими там "судя по", "говоря на" итп.

Comment: Обороты с предлогом "в качестве" обычно не выделяются запятыми, однако они могут обособляться для попутного пояснения, смыслового выделения или подчеркивания их смысла. Окончательное решение о пунктуации принимает автор текста.

Comment: @oleedd А почему в 3 без запятых? Ссылки есть?

Comment: Имеется в виду "без запятых получается это". Так у вас же без запятых, то есть вы указываете, что они не нужны, а потом ссылку в подтверждение хотите, весело.

Comment: У меня с примечанием - выбор запятых на усмотрение автора. Вы же говорите типа "без запятых и точка". Поэтому я и попросил ссылку. Ладно проехали.

Comment: @user190920 спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Запятая перед ‟или” ставится по причине того, что далее следует пояснение; ‟в переводе на простой язык” обособляется потому, что это вводное сочетание характеристики подачи, как вообще говоря, точнее, одним словом и т. д. Будет более очевидно, что это сочетание такого типа, если заменить его, например, на ‟по-простому” или на ‟по-простому говоря”. ‟В переводе с английского” трудно будет затянуть за уши в подобный вид вводных, но это в любом случае вводное, которое обособляется.

Comment: Я тоже думал о вводном, но это не объясняет всего. «В переводе с английского» вообще сомнительно считать вводным, потому что первейшим признаком вводных слов является независимость. А здесь это влияет на контекст.

Comment: Главный признак вводного это произношение как отступление, то есть когда предложение прерывается, произносится вводное и предложение продолжается. Второй главный признак, который следует из первого, это то, что вводное можно изъять, но предложение сохранит смысл, что в этом предложении можно сделать.

Comment: Отчасти соглашусь с вами, но в некоторых ситуациях «в переводе» нельзя изъять из предложения. Например: «На стене было написано "Abrajaharam", или в переводе с древнеигнийского «дом» — значит, он попал в место обитания древних игнийцев». Как видите, «в переводе» изъять из предложения нельзя, потому что потеряется контекст (персонаж сделал вывод, что попал в определенное место на основе языка). Ваш ответ мне в любом случае помог, но user19920 дал хорошее объяснение о непервообразных предлогах, поэтому будет честно отметить его ответ решением. Увы, вам могу поставить только плюсик.

Comment: Фразу ‟можно изъять вводное” лингвисты используют с аморфным, неотчётливым определением, как и многое другое. Если давать этой фразе какое-то более отчётливое определение, то тогда большинство вводных перестанут быть вводными в большинстве ситуаций.

Comment: @Theej Запятые нужны, чтобы отделить синтаксически фразу/слово от "в переводе", а то в плане синтаксиса получается: *или в переводе с древнеигнийского [слова] «дом»*. Можно просто считать обособленным оборотом. Если ссылаться на информацию из вводного словосочетания (в том числе за счёт противопоставления), то вводное перестаёт быть вводным, пример Sharon: *Сайт по официальным сообщениям закрыли, но у меня есть сведения, что нет.*

Comment: @JimKorbett спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @oleedd спасибо за объяснение.